# Cannot import C# library in sharepoint 2010 application page

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, gac

I want to reference a class library method inside the application aspx page but I keep getting the dreaded Yellow Screen of Death with the error message

> CS0103: The name 'Common' does not exist in the current context.

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092544/deploying-custom-dlls-in-sharepoint-2010) to add the project to GAC and I also restarted IIS via IIS Manager.

Here's my application page:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ApplicationPage1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SharePointProject1.Layouts.SharePointProject1.ApplicationPage1" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" />
<%= Common.Lib.Utility.GetStatusImage("approved") %>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
Application Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >
My Application Page
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: can you see the assembly where Common class is located in the GAC?  you need to look at v2.0 gac as SharePoint2010 is still based on 3.5 .Net version. <br/>  To ensure that it's in the gac you can bring gacutil.exe from sdk tools and run `gacutil /l <<assembly name w/o dll suffix>>`

Comment: If not, then you may have an assembly that does not have a strong name and thus cannot be GAC'd

Comment: Yes its strongly signed. I strongly signed my library project from Properties -> Signing

Comment: i just realized that i do not see the Namespace registration in your markup code.