# Custom DLL in SharePoint Application Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've added a custom DLL to a Custom Application page in SharePoint through VS 2010 like I would any other asp.net project. I then ran Build and Package and take the package and deploy it through PowerShell. When I navigate to the custom application page, it gives me a "File Not Found" SharePoint error. If I take out the code that uses the custom DLL, no errors. Any idea what I need to do to get this DLL working in a Custom Application Page in SharePoint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to deploy the DLL of course. In SharePoint you can do that via your package:

> Open your Package
>    Click on "Advanced" (on the bottom)
>    Add your external DLL and maybe even SafeControls for the web.config

As [I have explained in this post as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092544/deploying-custom-dlls-in-sharepoint-2010).

Comment: Thanks. I added it in the package and I still get "File Not Found" any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems to happen when I call "Document document = new Document();". The DLL is in the package and deploys to the GAC. Any idea why it would fail on that code? Thanks!