# packaging 3rd party dll into wsp

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dll

I have several 3rd party dll's for .net. I have the following requirements:
- They must each be in their own sharepoint 2010 wsp
- They must be deployed the bin, not the GAC

I'm having troubles accomplishing this. What steps need to be taken to do this?

I've tried creating a new sharepoint application, mapping bin, placing dll there then deploying.

I've tried creating new sharepoint application, adding the dll as a reference, selecting web application instead of global assembly cache and deploying.

Neither method has worked when I tried to use another webpart that required those dll's.

Edit - This page is an excellent example of what I need to do with 3rd party dll's but it doesn't have the details on how to do it. http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.sg/2012/06/sharepoint-package-your-external.html

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Check out following post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092544/deploying-custom-dlls-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: I cannot use that solution. These dll's need to be 1. in the bin 2. accessible by multiple applications and cannot be dependent on a random solution not being retracted. Each dll HAS to be it's own wsp. That is the requirement (by requirement I mean, defense department requirement.)

Answer (score 1):

Oké, getting your solution to deploy a DLL to the bin folder you need to change the deployment target from GAC to WebApplication. When the project is deployed the project assembly will be deployed to the bin folder of the project the DLLL will be located at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories[SiteName]\bin

[image]

For the second question I don't know what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe you can give some more context.

Comment: For sharepoint 2010, you'd have the 3rd party dll's in the gac for all apps to use. I'm being restricted in a new environment where I cannot put those dll's in the gac at all, either with deployment or manually. I can't just include a dll in a project then deploy it because if that is retracted it will delete the 3rd party dll from the bin. So, the dll say.. openXml.dll has to have its own deployment file. So I have to create a wsp that does nothing besides dump the dll to the bin folder. I have not gotten this to work. Hope that helps.